# Generating time series based on existing table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has something like this:

```
|    Zip    |     Population    |
+-----------+-------------------+
|    00001  |     100           |
|    00002  |     200           |
|    00003  |     250           |
```

and so on. I would like to generate a new table from the above table which looks something like this:

```
|    Date       |    Zip    |     Population    |
+---------------+-----------+-------------------+
|    01-01-2016 |   00001   |     100           |
|    01-02-2016 |   00001   |     100           |
|    01-03-2016 |   00001   |     100           |
|    ...        |   00001   |     100           |
|    31-12-2016 |   00001   |     100           |
|    01-01-2016 |   00002   |     200           |
|    01-02-2016 |   00002   |     200           |
|    01-03-2016 |   00002   |     200           |
|    ...        |   00002   |     200           |
|    31-12-2016 |   00002   |     200           |
```

and so on for all the rows in the original table at the top.

I have found a way to generate dates between a specific range (e.g., as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges)). I also think that I should use `LEFT JOIN` to achieve that?? I'm fairly new to SQL (or SQL Server, which is what I'm using at the moment). If so, what should I use as the join key? If someone could guide me through the process, I'd greatly appreciate the help. :) Thank you in advance for the answers!

Comment: No, not a left join but a cross join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - if you just want a quick way to do this, the following should give you what you're looking for

```
declare @OriginalTable table (zip varchar(5),population int)
declare @NewTable table (DateColumn date, zip varchar(5),population int)

insert into @OriginalTable values('00001',100)
insert into @OriginalTable values('00002',200)
insert into @OriginalTable values('00003',250)
declare @WorkDate Date = '2016-01-01'
declare @EndDate date = '2016-12-31'

WHILE @WorkDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @NewTable
    SELECT @WorkDate
        ,zip
        ,population
    FROM @OriginalTable

    SET @WorkDate = dateadd(day, 1, @WorkDate)
END

select * from @NewTable where zip='00001'
```

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in learning an efficient way of doing this using a set-based-methodology instead of a procedural (loop-based) methodology.

SQL Server typically performs set-based operations far more quickly than procedural operations.

The code below shows how to use a `select` statement to generate 366 rows containing dates from 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31 (2016 is a leap-year).  We then combine each of those rows with the "Zip" and "Population" columns of your source table, using a `CROSS JOIN`.

First, we setup a test-bed with your table, and a new destination table:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Zips') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Zips;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Zips
(
    Zip VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
    , Pop INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Zips (Zip, Pop)
VALUES ('00001', 100)
    , ('00002', 200)
    , ('00003', 250);

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ZipsWithDates') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.ZipsWithDates;
CREATE TABLE dbo.ZipsWithDates
(
    Zip VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
    , Pop INT NOT NULL
    , ZipDate DATE NOT NULL
);
```

This inserts rows, one for each day in the year, for each row in `Zips`:

```
;WITH dates AS (
SELECT TOP(366) /* 366 days in a leap-year, which 2016 is */
    TheDate = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o1.object_id, o2.object_id), CONVERT(DATE, N'2015-12-31'))
FROM sys.objects o1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
)
INSERT INTO dbo.ZipsWithDates (Zip, Pop, ZipDate)
SELECT z.Zip
    , z.Pop
    , d.TheDate
FROM dates d
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Zips z
```

This shows the contents of the new table:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ZipsWithDates;
```

And this is the output from the first few rows shows:

[image]

Note, you should always [specify the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), and please don't use [reserved words for column names](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/do-not-use-reserved-keywords/)

Comment: Wow, thank you very, very much for your detailed and easy-to-understand explanation! I accepted an earlier (procedural) solution already, but I upvoted your solution as well so that others can learn two different ways of doing things. Thank you very much for writing this up! :)

Comment: my pleasure, @user1330974